# How to use MediaPlayer in RecyclerViewAdapter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I just wanted to play some audio file(.mp3 for instance) in my Recyclerview Adapter class, I implemented it pretty easily, but I don't know why it is not playing as well as not showing any error for trace, have a look on code below, and guide me please:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PriceAdapter.PriceHolder, pos: Int) {
    holder.qt!!.text = questionsList[pos].priceText

    holder.qt!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (questionsList[pos].price == questionsList[pos].priceNow) {

      //This is where I wanted to implement my mediaplayer:

     var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? =MediaPlayer.create(it.context,R.raw.sound_file_1)
     mediaPlayer?.start()
     }
   }
```

It is not playing anything, rest are good, I have the raw mp3 file in res/raw/sound_file_1.mp3, what is possibly wrong with this?

Comment: Create a Singleton class that contains start , stop ,pause method and for each View use music path and pass it to start function  and then check if media.is already playing any music stop it and play given new path.

Comment: Would you care to write that for me, considering me as confused?

Comment: start doing a little bit RND for your better understanding..
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-android-media-player-singleton

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743351/how-to-use-a-mediaplayer-singleton

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380525/android-one-mediaplayer-instance-singleton

Comment: @RahulSingh so everytime onclick gets exceuted you will be playing same single file lik that

Answer (score 0):

According to Android docs on MediaPlayer implementation, MediaPlayer should be prepared before start playing.

> For reference MediaPlayer state diagram:

[image]

> A MediaPlayer object must first enter the Prepared state before
>   playback can be started.

Please check if you have performed these steps.

**What I feel you can do it as.**

Instead of creating the `MediaPlayer` in the `onBindViewHolder()` of `RecyclerView` pass it as a parameter from where the adapter is getting created, this will be efficient, because each time list is scrolled MediaPlayer object will get created, which I think is not a correct way to call. Open for discussion.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer if you go to this link you will find this comment in code snippet saying that // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you, Since I'm new dev, I will appreciate if you code some snippet for me for better understanding, will you?

Comment: Can you pass the MediaPlayer in a constructor of Adapter. Because It was getting acquired by multiple list items so it was creating a problem.

Comment: Yes, After passing in constructor?

Comment: @RahulSingh as mohamed says try to create single static instance for media player  and just call the play method to play ur raw file

Comment: Yes, I'm trying that, I'll update in no time, please wait.

Comment: After passing it to constructer mediaPlayer.create() method is not being shown, why is that?

Comment: You should implicitly specify the constructor value as MediaPlayer. Make sure that is done

Comment: Consider the code above and implement it for me, I relatively new to the coding, these terms are not clear for me without proper demonstration.